# name string_artist is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

So i'm trying to do a turtle controller program in Python but a message appears saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\PythonCode\TurtleController.py", line 35, in <module>
    string_artist(t_program)
NameError: name 'string_artist' is not defined
```

I've tried removing the string_artist and the problem didn't occur anymore. However without string_artist the turtle controller doesn't work anymore.

```
from turtle import *

def turtle_controller(do, val):
    do = do.upper()
    if do == 'F':
        forward(val)
    elif do == 'B':
        backward(val)
    elif do == 'R':
        right(val)
    elif do == 'L':
        left(val)
    elif do == 'U':
        penup()
    elif do == 'D':
        pendown()
    elif do == 'N':
        reset()
    else:
        print('unrecognized command')
instructions = '''Enter a program for the turtle:
example F100
N = New drawing
U/D = Pen Up/Down
F100 = Forward 100 (you can choose another number if you want)
B50 = Backwards 50
R90 = Right 90 deg
L45 = Left 45 deg'''
screen = getscreen()
while True:
    t_program = screen.textinput('Deseneaza in Python!', instructions)
    print(t_program)
    if t_program == None or t_program.upper() == 'END':
        break
    string_artist(t_program)
```

Comment: I don't see `string_artist` in the `turtle` documentation. Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: Hey sorry if I wasted my time so it looked like I missed the first code defining what string_artist should do but I fixed the program.